# Can I restore tensorflow training based on ckpt files in exported folder?

Tags: tensorflow, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

[image]

In the training folder, this is the last step: 80000. I can restore the training process based on this three ckpt files.

But in the exported folder, I can see another three ckpt files with smaller size. Can I use them to restore to continue the previous training process? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use checkpoints files to restore the training exactly where you have left off.
You can the example mentioned in the document [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#restore_and_continue_training), and it is designed to pick the oldest checkpoints, do modify it accordingly.

Also, refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint#restore) document for restore checkpoints.